# android: get list of google accounts on device without GET_ACCOUNTS permission and AccountPicker

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm already using `Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(...)` to let the user chose which account using to login, but I'd like to get the same list of accounts without user's interaction so no GET_ACCOUNTS permission, no AccountPicker activity.

Is there a way ?

Comment: I don't think so. That permission was created exactly to avoid programmers do what you wanna achieve

Comment: AccountPicker can be used without that permission and shows to the user (and the programmers) the accounts so, it could be possible, it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. When you invoke the AccountPicker then you are calling for result another Activity. A Google's Activity that knows the accounts on the device because it has permissions or knows because is Google's property. But not you. Not without those permissions.

You launch AccountPicker and you expect to get a result from the launched Activity. But that activity won't give you that information if the user doesn't select an account.

Comment: I was sure I could get the list of accounts but nope, you're totally right! I know I should create a new question, but maybe you know: is there a way to check if a certain email is a registered account in the device ? because this is in fact what I need, not a list. Thanks

Comment: Only choice you have is get the accounts on the device (then you'll get the email and the name for each one) and check if that string is equals to the one you're looking for.